# Using drawImage() to display a smaller section of larger image

Tags: java, user-interface

In attempt to use drawImage(), particularly:

`drawImage(Image img,int dx1,int dy1,int dx2,int dy2,int sx1,int sy1,int sx2,int sy2,Color bgcolor,ImageObserver observer)`

to scale a larger image into a smaller box for custom scroll-viewing I run into the issue of not understanding what each of the parameters do. After reading the description on the Oracle website I still feel uninformed. How exactly do each of these parameters work?

Comment: The API seems pretty clear to me, but I've done a lot of Swing coding, but having said that, I'm not sure what exactly you would need to be clarified. Perhaps a better question would be if you explained what you *think* the parameters should do, or just what in the API confuses you. Even better still would be if you posted a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your attempt to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

As the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) state...

> Parameters: 
> img - the specified image to be drawn. This method
>   does nothing if img is null. 
> dx1 - the x coordinate of the first
>   corner of the destination rectangle. 
> dy1 - the y coordinate of the
>   first corner of the destination rectangle. 
> dx2 - the x coordinate
>   of the second corner of the destination rectangle. 
> dy2 - the y
>   coordinate of the second corner of the destination rectangle. 
> sx1
>   - the x coordinate of the first corner of the source rectangle. 
> sy1 - the y coordinate of the first corner of the source
>   rectangle. 
> sx2 - the x coordinate of the second corner of the
>   source rectangle. 
> sy2 - the y coordinate of the second corner of
>   the source rectangle. 
> bgcolor - the background color to paint
>   under the non-opaque portions of the image. 
> observer - object to
>   be notified as more of the image is scaled and converted.

So the `d` parameters refer to the destination context, location and size.  The `s` parameters refer to source context, which part of the source image you want to render.  The `bgcolor` refers to the color you want to back fill the non-opaque portions of the result.